# Copy Localizable.Strings from one project to another

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to copy the Localizable.Strings files/folders from one Xcode project to another. I'm having difficulty seeing how to do it. I'd prefer not to have to re-create and then copy the content, but at the moment I can't find another way. Importing the folders with Add Existing or Drag and Drop from two Xcode windows doesn't seem to do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the folders in Finder (en.proj, it.proj, etc...) and copy them to another location. Then delete any files they contain that you don't need for your new project. And then import them to your new project.

Comment: That was what I tried, but I didn't end up with a Localizable.Strings item in my resources - just several folders. Can you explain the import step - I guess that's where I am going wrong ?

Comment: To have localizable strings you need to have the `Localizable.strings` file in several folders with the default names for the languages like `en.lproj` for English, `it.lproj` for Italian, etc... So you should have these 2 folders I named above and each one should contain a `Localizable.strings` file. When you import those 2 folders, Xcode will just display one Localizable.strings file that will expand to show 2 localizations.